# I can not figure out why my GridBagLayout is not following the rules

Tags: java, swing

I've been working on making the styling work, but I can not figure out why the gridbagconstraints that is supposed to exist doesn't work. It works to some degree, but then it also just won't work... the specific code is here:

```
private void initComponents() {



    usernameLabel = new JLabel();
    schedule = new CourseList();
    addCourseButton = new JButton();
    deleteCourseButton = new JButton();
    printScheduleButton = new JButton();
    feesButton = new JButton();
    helpLink = new SwingLink("help", "http://java.sun.com");
    logoutButton = new JButton();
    String u = getUsername();
    GridBagLayout gridBag = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints gbc;

    //Set Layout
    this.setLayout(gridBag);


    //Row One
    usernameLabel.setText("Welcome " + u);
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 6;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(20,10,10,10); //top, left, bottom, right
    gbc.anchor = gbc.LINE_END;
    gbc.fill = gbc.BOTH;
    this.add(usernameLabel, gbc);

    //Rows 2-4
    schedule.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("Course Schedule");
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridheight = 3;
    gbc.gridwidth = 6;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10); //top, left, bottom, right
    gbc.anchor = gbc.CENTER;
    gbc.fill = gbc.BOTH;
    this.add(schedule, gbc);

    //Row 5 - empty label
    JLabel hiddenLabel1 = new JLabel();
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 6;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 4;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10); //top, left, bottom, right
    gbc.fill = gbc.BOTH;
    this.add(hiddenLabel1, gbc);

    //Row 6
    addCourseButton.setText("Register");
    addCourseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            addCourseActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 5;
    gbc.ipadx = 10;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,5); //top, left, bottom, right
    gbc.anchor = gbc.CENTER;
    gbc.fill = gbc.HORIZONTAL;
    this.add(addCourseButton, gbc);

    deleteCourseButton.setText("Drop Delete Course");
    deleteCourseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            deleteCourseActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 5;
    gbc.ipadx = 10;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10,5,10,5); //top, left, bottom, right
    gbc.anchor = gbc.CENTER;
    gbc.fill = gbc.HORIZONTAL;
    this.add(deleteCourseButton, gbc);


    printScheduleButton.setText("Print Schedule");
    printScheduleButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            printScheduleActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc.gridx = 4;
    gbc.gridy = 5;
    gbc.ipadx = 10;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10,5,10,10); //top, left, bottom, right
    gbc.anchor = gbc.CENTER;
    gbc.fill = gbc.HORIZONTAL;
    this.add(printScheduleButton, gbc);


    //Row 7
    feesButton.setText("fees");
    feesButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            feesButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 6;
    gbc.ipadx = 10;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10,10,20,5); //top, left, bottom, right
    gbc.anchor = gbc.LINE_START; 
    gbc.fill = gbc.HORIZONTAL;
    this.add(feesButton, gbc);


    //Help Link postioning
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 6;
    gbc.ipadx = 10;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10,5,20,5); //top, left, bottom, right
    gbc.anchor = gbc.CENTER;
    gbc.fill = gbc.HORIZONTAL;
    helpLink.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    this.add(helpLink, gbc);

    logoutButton.setText("Logout");
    logoutButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            logoutButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc.gridx = 4;
    gbc.gridy = 6;
    gbc.ipadx = 10;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10,5,20,10); //top, left, bottom, right
    gbc.anchor = gbc.LINE_END; 
    gbc.fill = gbc.HORIZONTAL;
    this.add(logoutButton, gbc);

    setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(new MatteBorder(null), "", TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.TOP, new Font("Tahoma", 1, 14), new Color(255, 255, 255))); // NOI18N
    getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("Student Panel Welcome");

    setOpaque(false);
}
```

When I run it the layout gets drawn like this: [code running as written](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpYak.png)
Everything should be centered and look more akin to this: [design guide I wrote on a piece of paper in a meeting of sorts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiqG3.jpg)

If any other code is necessary to solve the problem, then let me know. I'm sure it is some stupid error on my part, but I can not for the life of me find any errors. And sorry if this is a trivial question, it's just been bugging me forever, and I need to move on to the other parts of the GUI.

Comment: I was going to suggest inline your images, but noticed the first one has profanity. Can you please remove the curse words, and then inline the images into the post?

Comment: Not allowed as I just created the account for this post. I can modify the image still for cleanliness. I tend to swear a lot in my comments and testing programs as it helps me make sense of what I'm doing.

Comment: When you have a complex layout, it's usually better to break it down into individual areas, particularly where the layout changes

Answer (score 2):

`gridwidth` can be a difficult thing to work with, a better approach might be to separate the layout into components and focus on the individual layout requirements separately

[image: Example]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JLabel title = new JLabel("Welcome");
            title.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"", "CRN", "Department", "Class", "Time", "Place"}, 5);
            add(new JScrollPane(new JTable(model)));

            JPanel options = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

            options.add(new JButton("Add course"), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            options.add(new JButton("Delete course"), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            options.add(new JButton("Print Schedule"), gbc);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            options.add(new JButton("Fees"), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            JLabel help = new JLabel("Help");
            help.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            options.add(help, gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            options.add(new JButton("Logout"), gbc);
            add(options, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }

    }

}
```

To help reduce the clutter of the UI, you might consider using a `JToolBar` instead of all the buttons along the bottom edge, see [How to Use Tool Bars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html) for more details

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean about focusing on individual components and whatnot. I have done that to some(much smaller) degree in another panel. I probably would have gone with some different design choices if I had thought about it more, but by the time we figured out what to do, we had already procrastinated to much to turn back. Thankfully I've gotten the code to where I can copy and paste most of it and just change a few names and whatnot. Thanks for the help anyways! The original problem I was facing dealt with gridwidth and weightx and all that.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need a `JPanel` to add the `GridBagLayout` to.

Here's this thing I found : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html
Hope that helps.

Comment: This is actually inside of a class that extends JPanel. I think I figured out the problem actually.... I was thinking about it too hard. In other words, I was thinking about the GridBagConstraints in the wrong way, and now I feel stupid having posted this now, lol.

Comment: Ah, alright, I figured it was something like that if you were this far. We all have those moments, though, great job on your part for figuring it out. :D

Answer (score 1):

So I was actually just thinking about it too hard. I needed to give all the lower buttons the same weight for them to align properly. I also did not need to use fill for the most part. The code that solved it(in case it can help anyone):

```
private void initComponents() {



    usernameLabel = new JLabel();
    schedule = new CourseList();
    addCourseButton = new JButton();
    deleteCourseButton = new JButton();
    printScheduleButton = new JButton();
    feesButton = new JButton();
    helpLink = new SwingLink("help", "http://java.sun.com");
    logoutButton = new JButton();
    String u = getUsername();
    GridBagLayout gridBag = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints gbc;

    //Set Layout
    this.setLayout(gridBag);


    //Row One
    usernameLabel.setText("<html><strong><u>Welcome </u></strong></html>" + u);
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 6;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(20,10,10,10); //top, left, bottom, right
    gbc.anchor = gbc.CENTER;
    this.add(usernameLabel, gbc);

    //Rows 2-4
    schedule.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("Course Schedule");
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridheight = 3;
    gbc.gridwidth = 6;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10); //top, left, bottom, right
    gbc.anchor = gbc.CENTER;
    gbc.fill = gbc.BOTH;
    this.add(schedule, gbc);

    //Row 5 - empty label
    JLabel hiddenLabel1 = new JLabel();
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 6;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 4;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10); //top, left, bottom, right
    gbc.fill = gbc.BOTH;
    this.add(hiddenLabel1, gbc);

    //Row 6
    addCourseButton.setText("Register");
    addCourseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            addCourseActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc.weightx = 0.5;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 5;
    gbc.ipadx = 5;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,5); //top, left, bottom, right
    gbc.anchor = gbc.LINE_END;
    this.add(addCourseButton, gbc);

    deleteCourseButton.setText("Drop Delete Course");
    deleteCourseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            deleteCourseActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc.weightx = 0.5;
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 5;
    gbc.ipadx = 5;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10,5,10,5); //top, left, bottom, right
    gbc.anchor = gbc.CENTER;
    this.add(deleteCourseButton, gbc);


    printScheduleButton.setText("Print Schedule");
    printScheduleButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            printScheduleActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc.weightx = 0.5;
    gbc.gridx = 4;
    gbc.gridy = 5;
    gbc.ipadx = 5;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10,5,10,10); //top, left, bottom, right
    gbc.anchor = gbc.LINE_START;
    this.add(printScheduleButton, gbc);


    //Row 7
    feesButton.setText("fees");
    feesButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            feesButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc.weightx = 0.5;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 6;
    gbc.ipadx = 5;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10,10,20,5); //top, left, bottom, right
    gbc.anchor = gbc.CENTER; 
    this.add(feesButton, gbc);


    //Help Link postioning
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc.weightx = 0.5;
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 6;
    gbc.ipadx = 5;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10,5,20,5); //top, left, bottom, right
    gbc.anchor = gbc.CENTER;
    helpLink.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    this.add(helpLink, gbc);

    logoutButton.setText("Logout");
    logoutButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            logoutButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc.weightx = 0.5;
    gbc.gridx = 4;
    gbc.gridy = 6;
    gbc.ipadx = 5;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10,5,20,10); //top, left, bottom, right
    gbc.anchor = gbc.CENTER; 
    this.add(logoutButton, gbc);

    setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(new MatteBorder(null), "", TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.TOP, new Font("Tahoma", 1, 14), new Color(255, 255, 255))); // NOI18N
    getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("Student Panel Welcome");

    setOpaque(false);
}
```

Results in:[running as correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9DjZ.png)

Comment: So this was really long ago, but I thought I would reach out and mention it; it appears you never marked your answer as the accepted answer, and I would encourage you to do so so that your question appears as answered.